# Customer Custom Tab data cant save in admin

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, event-observer

I have a custom module which is used to add a custom module in customer section in admin. I have added this tab successfully and now I am trying to save custom data that obtain through custom tab in a custom table. For that I am using an observer method and which is shown below

```
<config>
-----------------
<global>
    <events>
      <adminhtml_customer_prepare_save>
          <observers>
              <save_customnewtab_data>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>customernewtab/observer</class>
                  <method>saveCustomerNewTabData</method>
              </save_customnewtab_data>
          </observers>
      </adminhtml_customer_prepare_save>
    </events>   
    --------------
 </global>
 ---------
 </config>
```

and my observer is shown below

```
<?php

class Mysite_Customernewtab_Model_Observer
{
    public function saveCustomerNewTabData($observer){

        if (isset($observer['customer'])) 
        {
            $customer = $observer['customer']->getData();
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($customer);
            die();

        } 
        else 
        {
            //Do something with the customer
        }
    }
}
```

this is the extract of phtml file which I am using to render the content of my custom tab

```
<!-- some contents here -->
<tr>
<td>
    <table class="form-list" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                    <td class="value">
            <input id="customer_nick_name" class=" required-entry input-text required-entry" type="text" value="" name="customernewtab[customer_nick_name]" />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<?php /*profile pic section*/ ?>
 <tr>
<td>
    <table class="form-list" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="customernewtab-prof-pic" style=" margin-left: 250px;margin-top: 30px;">                
                <input id="customernewtab_file_name" type="hidden" name="customernewtab[customer_photo]" value=""  />
            <input id="customnewtab_file" type="file" name="customer_prof_pic" value="" />

            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Now see my observer output, while editing an existing customer data with my custom data has set along with it.

```
Array
(
[entity_id] => 3
[entity_type_id] => 1
[attribute_set_id] => 0
[website_id] => 1
[email] => rajeev_ktomy@yahoo.in
[group_id] => 1
[increment_id] => 
[store_id] => 1
[created_at] => 2014-03-10T04:23:00-07:00
[updated_at] => 2014-03-12 07:22:00
[is_active] => 1
[disable_auto_group_change] => 0
[firstname] => test
[lastname] => test
[password_hash] => 4de63e833f14934a3c5fd4213496a13c:n0seA0z1a135nmY3rtbTkUAmkTpiomzw
[created_in] => English
[prefix] => 
[middlename] => 
[suffix] => 
[taxvat] => 
[dob] => 
[gender] => 
[is_subscribed] => 
)
```

As you can see my custom data is missing in the output. My question is

1) Why my custom datas `customer_nick_name` and `customer_photo` are not visible in the output ?
2)What is wrong in my code ?
3) Is this the correct way to save custom tab data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why my custom datas customer_nick_name and customer_photo are not visible in the output ?

Because they are not processed, this happens here:

```
\Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController::saveAction
/** @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
$customerForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
$customerForm->setEntity($customer)
    ->setFormCode('adminhtml_customer')
    ->ignoreInvisible(false)
;

$formData = $customerForm->extractData($this->getRequest(), 'account');
```

You need to add the attributes which should be parsed to the `customer_form_attribute` table, if you don't use the magento logic.

> What is wrong in my code ?
>   Is this the correct way to save custom tab data ?

But why aren't you just add a new attribute and let magento do the rest? Magento should render the attributes and show them to you ... and save them of course.

There are lots of blog articles how to add a customer attribute, e.g. [this one from elsondesigns](http://elsondesigns.com/Blog/Magento-programmatically-create-customer-attribute/).

```
$this->addAttribute($entity, 'some_attribute', array(
    'type' => 'text',               /* input type */
    'label' => 'Some Attribute',    /* Label for the user to read */
    'input' => 'text',              /* input type */
    'visible' => TRUE,              /* users can see it */
    'required' => FALSE,            /* is it required, self-explanatory */
    'default_value' => 'default',   /* default value */
    'adminhtml_only' => '1'         /* use in admin html only */
));
```

Adding an image field is possible, the part with the enctype is a little bit tricky (good catch!) and I think you need an observer for it... and I'm WRONG. Everything fine:

```
\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Form
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'        => 'edit_form',
        'action'    => $this->getData('action'),
        'method'    => 'post',
        'enctype'   => 'multipart/form-data'
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for write in. I need to upload an image field also... is that possible with attributes? and one is it necessary to add `enctype => multipart/form-data` for this purpose in customer admin section ?

Comment: updated my answer, adding image is no problem, enctype is already set

Comment: so I have two more doubts exist related to this. how can I display these attributes in my custom tab(going through the given tutorial, i think my phtml file that render content of my custom tab now is waste :)). second for any section in admin, can I use this 'attribute' trick to add a custom tab and save it along with the rest of data of that section? @fabian

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I would give it a try like with product attributes to just add the `group`, may work. It is processed, because `class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`

Comment: according to your suggestion, I used 'attribute' approach to add fields in my customer tab. I have added attribute successfully and it showed in account tab also and from there I can put input to that attribute. But I want this attribute in my custom tab itself. I have tried a lot and none seems to be working. see this new qn :http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16971/display-custom-attribute-in-custom-tab . can you shed some light on this issue. It sicks me.. @fabian

Comment: No, sorry. I never dig into the customer tab generation. But all the Tabs have their own class implementation, therefore I would assume, they are not auto generated.

Comment: where should I can find an answer for this question??? trying for 3 days without success :( Nobody responds to my question (

Comment: Have a look in the classes `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_*` where they are loaded and how they are processed. I think they are loaded here: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs, so I think you "just" need to add your own tab there. Unfortunately I don't see any event which could be used, so I think you have to rewrite the whole block to add your own tab.