# Display Custom Attribute in Custom Tab

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, custom-attributes, module

I have a module which use to `add a custom tab` in `customer section` in admin. I have created custom tab successfully. Now I want to add some custom attributes that I have added through installation file of my module to this custom tab. What is the best way for doing this?

My current ideas are these

1. Add these custom attributes through the file `local/Mysite/Mymodule/Block
   /Adminhtml/Mymodule/Edit/Tab/Mycustomform.php`(this file use to render my 
   custom tab content)
2. Define a `phtml file` to render the content of my custom tab in above 
   mentioned file(through `_construct()` method) and then using some html and php script display my attributes.

Which method is better? Is there any other better method to achieve this? Please share your thoughts...

Comment: gt; reference name="my.account.wrapper" lgt; add the phtml file xml.